# How to run Rmarkdown zsh chunk on Windows 10?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, zsh

As of macOS Catalina, the default shell is zsh so I decided to make the transition on my mac and can run code chunks as such with no issues:

```
ls
```

However, when running on Windows 10. I get the following error:

```
zsh is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I followed these [instructions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-zsh-and-oh-my-zsh-windows10/) to successfully install zsh on Windows 10.

Is this even possible or should I just stick to bash code chunks to make my code reproducible on Windows as well?

Answer (score 0):

- I started off by following thus tutorial to install bash and zsh on Windows: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-zsh-and-oh-my-zsh-windows10/
- Then I downloaded and installed RStudio Preview: https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/
  (Tested with Version 1.3.926)
- Open RStudio and navigate to `Tools -> Global Options -> Terminal -> New Terminals open with Custom`